# HAProxy redirect port and mask url

Tags: haproxy

I have a couple of webservers that are reachable directly through the following URL:

> https://abcd.example.com:8445/desktop/container/landing.jsp?locale=en_US
>   https://wxyz.example.com:8445/desktop/container/landing.jsp?locale=en_US

I need to use HAProxy to loadbalance between the two and use the following URLs instead when hitting the frontend:

> http://1234.example.com/desktop/container/landing.jsp?locale=en_US
>   or
>   https://1234.example.com:8445/desktop/container/landing.jsp?locale=en_US

So other requirements beside the two above:

1. If initial traffic is port 80, convert to port 8445
2. Mask the URL so that on the browser while it redirected to https and port to 8445, the host remains intact, like so: https://1234.example.com:8445/desktop/container/landing.jsp?locale=en_US

Here's my config so far:

```
frontend WebApp_frontend
    mode http
    bind 10.4.34.11:80
    acl is80 dst_port 80
    http-request set-uri https://%[req.hdr(Host)]:8445%[path]?%[query] if is80
    default_backend WebApp-backend

backend WebApp_backend
    description WebApp
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    server webserver1 10.2.89.222:8445 check inter 5s fall 3 rise 5 downinter 1m ssl verify none
    server webserver2 10.4.89.223:8445 check inter 5s fall 3 rise 5 downinter 1m ssl verify none
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that when you access the frontend, HAProxy will redirect you to any of the webservers and force your client to hit the webserver directly instead of through the HAProxy. I need the connection to remain through the HAProxy.

Answer (score 0):

If all your application is doing is redirecting to HTTPs then you should probably just handle that directly within HAProxy.  You might want to also explore whether your application supports X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-Host.

Another option is you can have HAProxy rewrite the redirects from the backend application to the hostname you choose.  Using HAProxy 2.1 you would do something like this:

```
http-response replace-header location https?://[^:/]*(:?[0-9]+/.*)  https://1234.example.com\1 if { status 301:302 }
```